# The most secure network library for Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, certificate-pinning

Recently I have used the `retrofit 2.3.0` networking library in my project. I have also implemented `SSL pinning` for securing the app, using the `CertificatePinner` class in the `Okhttp` and thus Retrotif.

However, after another team has run a comprehensive `penetration test` on our APK, they have been successful to `tamper with the CertificatePinner` class in the Okhttp client, resulting in `gaining access to the plain messages` that are being sent to the web services.

Since we have to `exclude Retrofit and Okhttp classes from the proguard` process, by writing their specific keep-rules, we conclude this was the main cause of their successful reverse engineering.

Anyway, the following questions have arised considering the situation :

1- Why in the first place, the retrofit and okhttp need proguard rules ?

2- What is the possible secure workaround for this problem ?

3- Do we need to replace the Retrofit with yet another library like Volley or AsyncHttpClient ?

Comment: "Why in the first place, the retrofit and okhttp need proguard rules ?" -- what makes you think that they are needed? [Jake Wharton doesn't think that any are needed for OkHttp, for example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2230#issuecomment-236068544). "What is the possible secure workaround for this problem ?" -- there is none. Anything can be reverse-engineered. The point behind certificate pinning is to prevent MITM attacks. Hacked clients can always get the plaintext.

Comment: I don't know how the team tampered the CertificatePinner, but I assume they just modified the APK. Therefore replacing the Java based implementation will not help you. You have to apply a harding tool that protects your APK as a whole and/or switch to native implementation (no Java). That will make reverse-engineering a bit harder but not impossible.

Comment: @Robert Do you know any samples about how to implement hardening for APK in android ? any frameworks or routines ?

Comment: The Answer is simple: Buy a good harding framework. Everything you will be able to implement on your own in 6 months can be hacked by a semi-skilled attacker in 1-2 hours.